# How to match data types in Objective-c to Swift protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

Trying to port Objective-c code to Swift and I'm pretty new to Swift. I added bridging header and included all the necessary headers to it. In my Swift class I need to use the following protocol below:

```
@protocol MyProtocolDelegate

- (void)doSomeStuff:(NSDictionary *)stuff;

@end
```

In my Swift class I have the following code:

```
func doSomeStuff(stuff:Dictionary<String,String>)
{
...
}
```

I get an error here:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,MyProtocolDelegate  <-- Type ViewController doesn't conform to protocol MyProtocolDelegate
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: try replace `Dictionary<String,String>` with `[String,String]` or add `@ObjC`

Comment: YAY!!! I figured! stuff: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)...I tried AnyObject before, but without !...UGH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, a plain `NSDictionary *` is bridged to `[NSObject: AnyObject]!`.

To get `Dictionary<String,String>`, you would have to declare it in Objective-C as

```
- (void)doSomeStuff:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *)stuff;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func doSomeStuff(stuff: NSDictionary)
```

You don't need to specify type if you don't want to.

Comment: this doesn't work for some reason this worked ( stuff: [NSObject : AnyObject]! )

Comment: This is a weird behaviour, having to specify a type in order to get the dictionary parameter to be recognized, also i see that you are unwrapping it, you're not suppose to have to.